# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response(Jenkins API)

Tags: angular, jenkins-api

I see below error when trying to access Jenkins API(https://jenkinsbox:3000/api/json) using angular service with Basic authentication providing in headers.

Error:

> Failed to load http://jenkinsbox:30000/api/json?&tree=jobs[name]:
>   Request header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type':  'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
})

getjobslists(): Observable<jobs[]>{
   this.url = "https://jenkinsbox:3000/api/json"
   console.log("getting data..")
   return this.http.get<jobs[]>(this.url + "/api/json?&tree=jobs[name]",this.httpOptions)

    .pipe(map(function(res){
       //console.log(res);
       return res;
    }))
 }
```

And configured CORS in Jenkins using CORS Support plugin - 
[image]

I think I'm missing something in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" from Jenkins end. please assist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to allow Authorization header also.
So add **Authorization** into **Access-control-Allow-Headers**